# How to resolve scalac: Error: assertion failed:?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, scala-3, java-18

I'm pretty new to Scala programming. I pulled a code from GIT into IntelliJ. However, I'm getting the below error while compiling. I have installed latest Scala version (3.2.0) on to my mac (JDK18 is also installed).

```
scalac: Error: assertion failed: 
  No RuntimeVisibleAnnotations in classfile with ScalaSignature attribute: class DefaultFormats
     while compiling: /Users/usr/mainProg.scala
        during phase: globalPhase=typer, enteringPhase=namer
     library version: version 2.13.9
    compiler version: version 2.13.9
  reconstructed args: -classpath <Several Jar file locations>
  last tree to typer: Ident(net)
       tree position: line 3 of /Users/usr/mainProg.scala
            tree tpe: net.type
              symbol: final package net
   symbol definition: final package net (a ModuleSymbol)
      symbol package: <none>
       symbol owners: package net
           call site: package processing in package delta in package delta
```

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: How is `apache-spark` tag relevant? Is your code from git Spark-related?

Comment: What is in the file `mainProg.scala`?

Comment: Yes it has spark-related code. Unfortunately, I can't share the exact code as it is taken from one of the production ready systems.

Comment: How do you build your project? Sbt? Just in case, did you try `sbt clean compile` (to exclude Intellij)?

Comment: If you can't share the exact code maybe you can prepare a little different code reproducing the issue. It seems you're using json4s `DefaultFormats` with spark.

Comment: In principle this should work. For example with [Scala-cli](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org) `$ scala-cli --scala 3.2.0 --jvm 18 --dependency org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.13:3.3.0` `scala> import org.json4s.DefaultFormats` it's ok. So please provide reproduction of any kind.

Comment: The code contains an import statement as - _**`import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats`**_.  Does this has anything to do with the error I'm getting?

Comment: I tried your suggestion running `sbt clean compile` as well, but still the same error.

Comment: `$ scala-cli --scala 3.2.0 --jvm 18 --dependency org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.13:3.3.0 --dependency net.liftweb:lift-json_2.13:3.5.0` `scala> import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats` ok.

Comment: Not much can be done without reproduction. Looks like a bug (not complete compatibility with latest JDKs). Are you sure you need the latest JDK with Scala?

Comment: I have tried with both JDK19 as well as JDK18.

Comment: Did you try to prepare reproduction?

Comment: I meant that jdk 8 is still best tested for Scala. Do you use features of newer JDKs?

Comment: Didn't you manage to prepare a reproduction?

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

- Try Scala 3.1.3 for JDK 18

(although it's the *minimal* version recommended for JDK 18, so 3.2.0 should work, please report about Scala 3 bugs at the [tracker](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues)).

- Or JDK 19 for Scala 3.2.0.

(About [RuntimeVisibleAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936139/runtimevisibleannotations-and-runtimeinvisibleannotations-how-to-access-from-c).)

Comment: I tried this option too. But no luck.